# Hide negatives on Line Chart

Tags: vb.net, charts, crystal-reports-2005

I have [a line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZEf3.png) on a Visual Basic 2005 Crystal Report.  The thing is that I can't make "Y" scale start from 0 and not showing negatives.  I have set the min value on chart options but when I run the report, the "Y" scale shows negatives.

How can I set the min value for "Y" scale from code behind?

Comment: Is there an option for "automatically set chart options"?  If so, uncheck that option.

Comment: Hello Jim.  I have unchecked that option and setted values manually for scale but when I execute the report it shows negative values.